# NetLogo: Topology: An error occurs when the turtle reaches the end (max-pxcor) of a boxed or cylindrical world with ends

Tags: netlogo, forward, topology

I tried the following syntax but got the following error.

Error messages: TURTLES-ON expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.

In the 2D screen when an error message was issued, an error occurred when the turtle reached the rightmost cell. If the sintax "forward 1", this case works well withour any error. But I need to use the "forward 1 * 0.1" syntax with "tick-advance 0.1".

I already saw the following description, but I do not solve it still now.Does anyone know a good way? Thank you in advance.

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology

The following is an example syntax:

```
ask turtles with [xcor < max-pxcor][ 
if not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1
[forward 1 * 0.1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `can-move?` reporter referenced in your link is one way (and references another: `patch-ahead distance != nobody`). In the [dictionary definition](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#can-move), it notes that the reporter reports `true` when the turtle could move some distance without violating topology- in other words, if the turtle can move to an existing patch. Any patches "off the edge" of a world without world wrapping do not exist, and so return `nobody`.

`tick` or `tick-advance` shouldn't figure into this issue, as the evaluation of the `patch-ahead` is done by each turtle independent of timing. For example, here's a toy model that doesn't have `tick` or `tick-advance` at all:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 200 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here ]
    pd
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let speed 1 * 0.1
  ask turtles [
    if can-move? speed and not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead speed [
      fd speed
    ]
  ]
end
```

Note that I've turned world-wrapping off entirely, and get a result like what is shown below- no errors, and turtles have stopped moving either because there is a turtle in there way or because they've bumped up against the edge of the world:

[image]